# (WordPress/UltimateMember) Hook functions not working in custom plugin / child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, ultimate-member

So I'm trying to extend UltimateMember's functionality with a custom plugin called "testFamily". In the plugin I have testFamily.php, with these functions:

```
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../ultimate-member/includes/core/um-actions-login.php'; 

function register_hooks() {
    add_action( 'um_user_login', 'onLogin', 999, 1 );
    add_action( 'init' , 'testInit');
}

function testInit() {
    echo "Hello";
}
    
function onLogin($userid, $args) {
    // do some stuff after logging in...
}

register_hooks();
```

The `init` callback works fine, but the `um_user_login` callback doesn't run at all. I even set the function code to `die();` and it doesn't work.
Calling `function_exists('um_user_login')` returns true.

I've also tried to implement it as a child theme like the docs say, but it doesn't run then either.
I've tried example code from the website

Answer (score 0):

I used a different hook: `um_on_login_before_redirect`  and it worked just fine.